# Installing Kubuntu

Tags: installation, kubuntu

I want to install Kubuntu (not sure if I should keep Windows 8 alongside or just delete it considering I don't have any info on it anyway) so when I'm at the partitioning stage it asks me about LVM and encrypted LVM, what do they mean and which should I choose? I couldn't really find any detailed answers regarding LVM on the net. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[LVM wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29)

If you're just using it for home use, it's probably better to stick with the standard partitioning.